# From DateTime to String to DateTime Conversion

Tags: vb.net

```
Date purchaseDate = #6/2/2023 03:57:00 PM#
Dim purchaseDT As String = purchaseDate.ToShortDateString()
Dim purchaseDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(purchaseDT, "MM/dd/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

My goal is to convert this `#6/2/2023 03:57:00 PM#` to `06/02/2023 12:00:00 AM`

Would anyone help me please converting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual aim is to simply remove the time portion from the `Date` value then there's no need to do any conversion.

```vb
Dim dateWithTime = #6/2/2023 03:57:00 PM#
Dim dateWithoutTime = dateWithTime.Date
```

The `Date` property of a `DateTime` returns a new `DateTime` with the time zeroed, so effectively just the date.

In case you aren't aware, the .NET `DateTime` type and the VB `Date` type are the same thing - much like .NET `Int32` and VB `Integer` are the same thing - and they always include a date and a time. To represent just the date, you zero the time to midnight, which appears to be what you're trying to do. .NET has recently added the `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` types, so you can use them in certain circumstances. `DateTime` is so entrenched ion .NET though, there are still many circumstances where you need to use it even if you want to represent only a date without a time.

EDIT:

I just realised that I'm repeating some of Joel's advice, so I would expect his answer to be preferred over mine. I'll leave mine though, as hopefully some of the explanation may help.

Answer (score 4):

You want this:

```
Dim purchaseDate As String = (New DateTime(2023, 6, 2, 15, 57,0)).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Or given the initial `purchaseDate` value:

```
Dim purchaseDate As Date = #6/2/2023 03:57:00 PM#
Dim result As String = purcaseDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

See them work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/kAzY0L

Note the final variables are declared as **string**. `DateTime` values themselves do NOT have a text format of any kind. It's only when they are converted to strings that you get to pick a format.

With that in mind, it's also generally best to *keep things as unformatted DateTime values for as long as possible*, and wait to convert to a formatted string until the last possible moment. (This advice is also good for numeric types).

Comment: Nice method, [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-7.0) is the key, as it strips the time, so the resulting instance has 12 am time.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim purchaseDate As DateTime = #6/2/2023 03:57:00 PM#
Dim purchaseDateString As String = purchaseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
Dim formattedPurchaseDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(purchaseDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Console.WriteLine(formattedPurchaseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM"))
```

I used the ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") method to convert the DateTime to a string in the format "MM/dd/yyyy". Then, I used DateTime.ParseExact to parse the formatted string back into a DateTime object.

Therefore I used ToString("MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM") to format the resulting DateTime object with the desired format, including the time part set to midnight.
This should give you the output in the format "06/02/2023 12:00:00 AM" as you specified.

Hope this could helpful for you.